oracle client and networking components were not found while try to connect oracle database in visual studios
When I try to connect my Oracle database to Visual Studio, it shows an error. However, I'm having trouble installing and configuring the Oracle Client properly. Can you guide me through the correct installation and configuration process?
step by step guide
